# 3 columns, 2 spreadsheets, only want matching data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is the scenero.  Two spreadsheets, both containing columns for first name, last name and dob.

I want to make a list of only the names that are on both spreadsheets.

How?

Thank you!

Comment: use `VLOOKUP`, google for it's usage.

Comment: Put both data in same worksheet and use Conditional Formatting to detect duplicates. Or resume data with Pivot Tables and get only those where count are 2.

Comment: I should add I have roughly 10k rows on one sheet and 2 k on the other

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that we have 3 sheets, Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3

Modify if needed and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook

        'Set Sheet3 as wsResults
        Set wsResults = .Worksheets("Sheet3")
        'Clear wsResults
        wsResults.UsedRange.Clear
        'Loop all ws
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            'If ws name <> Sheet3
            If ws.Name <> "Sheet3" Then
                'Find the last row of wsResults
                Lastrow = wsResults.Cells(wsResults.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                'Copy ws used range after wsResults last row
                ws.UsedRange.Copy wsResults.Range("A" & Lastrow + 1)

            End If

        Next ws

        'Remove duplicates from wsResults based of first 3 columns
        With wsResults
            .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
                Header:=xlNo
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```